# Variável está sempre com valor, quando deveria ser null em determinados momentos

Tags: c#

Tenho esse código: Esse `rptAprovaDocumento` é um repeater

```
public List<ENTSISRegistroPendencia> RegistrarPendencia()
{
    CheckBox vchkTornarObrigatorio = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < rptAprovaDocumento.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        vchkTornarObrigatorio = (CheckBox)rptAprovaDocumento.Items[i].FindControl("chkTornarObrigatorio");

        if (vchkTornarObrigatorio != null)
        {
            if (!vchkTornarObrigatorio.Checked)
            {
                ventRegPendencia.IcDocObrigatorio = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                ventRegPendencia.IcDocObrigatorio = 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ventRegPendencia.IcDocObrigatorio = 0;
        }    
    }
}
```

Como funciona. Esse `repeater` tem uma table que lista esses registros. Esse checkbox ele aparece em uma determinada situação. A primeira vez que o analista de crédito vai fazer a sua análise ele aparece, com a palavra "Tornar Obrigatório". Esse é o text dele. Quando o analista checa e devolve para as lojas, o usuário lojista consegue ver esse documento listado que o analista tornou obrigatório. Ao upar esse documento e devolver para o analista, agora ele aparece para o analista não mais como um Checkbox(Tornar Obrigatório) mais dois RadioButton: Aprovar e Reprovar. Bem, acontece que nessa posição de "i" dentro do repeater, a var `vchkTornarObrigatorio` deveria vir NULL, certo? Pensei em nular todas as variáveis no final do `FOR`, mas achei isso meio gambiarra, pois já disse que quero o valor da var na posição "i" dentro do repeater, de acordo com o código postado. Penso em inicializar a var dentro do `FOR`, mas também me cheira a gambi, não tenho certeza. É um problema de lógica e peço ajuda dos colegas para resolver essa tralha. Como nular essa var dentro do for.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptAprovaDocumento" runat="server" 
        onitemdatabound="rptAprovaDocumento_ItemDataBound"> 
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table width="1000">
                <thead>
                    <th width="400">
                        Tipos de documento
                    </th>
                    <th width="150">
                    </th>
                    <th>
                    </th>
                </thead>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfCdTipoDocumento" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("CdTipoDocumento")%>' />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfCdPendencia" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("CdPendencia")%>' />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfCdDocumento" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("CdDocumento")%>' />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfIcAprovado" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("IcAprovado")%>' />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfIcDocObrigatorio" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("IcDocObrigatorio")%>' />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfCdMotivo" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("CdTipoMotivoRecusa")%>' />

                    <%--<strong><a href="/UpLoads/<%# Eval("DsPathDocumento")%>" class="linkUpload"><%# Eval("NmTipoDocumento")%></a></strong>--%>

                    <strong><a <%# Eval("DsPathDocumento") != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("DsPathDocumento").ToString()) ? String.Concat("href='/UpLoads/", Eval("DsPathDocumento"), "'","class='linkUpload'") : "style='cursor: default; color:#000000;' class='disabled'" %>>
                        <%# Eval("NmTipoDocumento") %>
                    </a></strong>                      

                    <asp:Label ID="lblDtCriacao" Text='' runat="server" /><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblNmObrigatorio" Text='<%# Eval("NmTipoObrigatorio") %>' runat="server" Font-Bold="True" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbIctAprovado" CssClass="radiobuttonAprovaReprova" onclick="javascript:MostraEscondeControle(this);"
                        runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" TextAlign="left" RepeatColumns="0" RepeatDirection="Vertical"
                        CausesValidation="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbIctAprovado_SelectedIndexChanged" RepeatLayout="UnorderedList">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Aprovar</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Reprovar</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkTornarObrigatorio" runat="server" Text="Tornar Obrigatório" />
                    <br />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="cmbCdMotivoRecusa" runat="server" Enabled="false" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="É necessário aprovar ou reprovar este documento para prosseguir."
                        ControlToValidate="rbIctAprovado" ValidationGroup="grupoAprovaReprova" Text=""></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: pode postar o Markup destes Repeater?

Comment: Editei e posteii o markup.

Comment: não estou vendo nenhuma condição que torna o chkTornarObrigatorio inativo, invisivel ou inexistente, como você está ocultando o mesmo?

Comment: Você poderia colocar o trecho do codigo onde o `chkTornarObrigatorio` é desativado ou removido?

Comment: Ele não é removido. Apenas ele aparece ou não, de acordo com o que o analista fez. Eu acho que devo mudar minha lógica aí no caso, ou seja, vou criar um método que pegue a situação do documento em uma análise anterior, aí sim, eu sei que ele não poderá mudar seu status nunca mais.

Comment: então neste caso você deve verificar a propriedade `Visible`, um `chkTornarObrigatorio.Visible` no lugar de `vchkTornarObrigatorio != null` deve resolver

Comment: Vou testar e posto. Nem pensei nessa hipótese. Caso resolva, poste esse comentário como resposta para eu finalizar.

Comment: Deu certo numa parte e referente ao post inicial resolveu, mas não conclui o problema, mas é outra coisa. Poste o seu comentário como resposta para finalizar esse post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O comando `rptAprovaDocumento.Items[i].FindControl("chkTornarObrigatorio") as CheckBox` simplesmente retorna o `CheckBox` `chkTornarObrigatorio` associado ao item atual.

Como todos os `RepeaterItem` possuem um `CheckBox` `chkTornarObrigatorio`, então ele será encontrado em todos os itens da interação, idepedente dele está invisivel ou desativado.

**EDIT**

Como identificado em conversa com o Autor da Pergunta, encontramos uma resolução parcial.

> então neste caso você deve verificar a propriedade Visible, um
>   chkTornarObrigatorio.Visible no lugar de vchkTornarObrigatorio != null
>   deve resolver

Comment: o correto seria eu nular ele no fim do for ou declarar ele no começo ou mudar a lógica.

Comment: você redeclarar ele no inicio do for ou invalidar o mesmo no final não vai mudar o comportamento atual, pois o método `...Item[i].FindControl("chkTornarObrigatorio")` sempre vai retornar um `CheckBox`, em resumo, o seu problema não está no mal entendimento do laço for, mas do funcionamento do Repeater.

Comment: Ok, vou ter que repensar outra forma de fazer isso, valeu.